# jquery update css property with array element

Tags: jquery, html, css, json

my current css looks like this for class "firstTri"

```
.firstTri{
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 160px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 160px solid transparent;

    border-left: 160px solid gray;
}
```

I want to change the color of this triangle to yellow, so I have:

```
$('.firstTri').css("border-right","160px solid yellow");
```

which works but what if I want to update the color with the values in this array:

```
samples = [
        { 
        values : ["blue", "red", "green", "blue", "yellow"],
        },
        { 
        values : ["...etc"],
        }

];
```

I was thinking something like this:

```
 $('.firstTri').css("border-right","160px solid samples[i].values[j]");
```

i and j increment, i increments after j ends

For example, the second index is red, so that would be

```
samples[0].values[1]
```

Comment: Sting concatenation -> `$('.firstTri').css("border-right","160px solid " + samples[i].values[j]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting a string into the CSS value. It cannot contain variables.
If you would write something like this

```
$('.firstTri').css("border-right","160px solid " + samples[i].values[j]);
```

It should work.